# Consistent thumbnails with jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, thumbnails

I'm using thumbnails in a JQuery mobile list view.

The list end up looking very inconsistent because I have a mix of thumbnails .. some tall, some wide ..

What's the best way to make the display look better.

[image: Here's what the current looks like]

[image: Here's what it looks like after applying the suggestion below]

Comment: Have you tried applying some css like img.my-thumbnails { width: 80px; height: 80px; }?

Comment: Check this article http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/odd-sized-thumbnails-in-listview/

Comment: Nice article, @Omar.  BTW - I want to go to the BeerBaconandBourbonFestival!!!

Comment: Thanks, that's really not a bad start. I was thinking of mixing something like this with that - http://demosthenes.info/blog/492/Auto-Generate-Image-Thumbnails-With-CSS

Comment: I added a pic of what it looks like now after making the above edit. I would have added the image as part of the comment but does not look I can do that.